# Change default permissions for new files and folders

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, chown

Every time I create a new file or folder in Linux, it is accessible for r/w by myself, not the group. I want to change my system setting such that every new file or folder will be automatically accessible by the group. Is there anyway?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the article:

```
chmod g+s <directory>  //set gid 
setfacl -d -m g::rwx /<directory>  //set group to rwx default 
setfacl -d -m o::rx /<directory>   //set other
```

Next we can verify:

```
getfacl /<directory>
```

Output:

```
file: ../<directory>/
owner: <user>
group: media
flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

More info : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/applying-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-within-a-specific-folder-605129/

Comment: Looks like a copy pasta answer from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1315

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using the `umask` utility. [What is Umask and How To Setup Default umask Under Linux?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)

You can setup a script that starts automatically on boot which executes the command

```
umask 777
```

to give everyone read/write and execute permission, for example.

Comment: This is inaccurate, `umask` works the other way around than `chmod`. Setting an umask of 777 would give nobody permission to do anything (the permissions set would be 000).