# set default file permission to read, write and execute in linux

Tags: linux, security, unix, file-permissions, umask

I need to set default file creation permissions for `everyone` to `777` [`rwx`], however `umask` uses `666` for files:

- If I need permissions to be `444`, I would issue `umask 222` [`666 - 222 = 444`], but the problem is I need to set them to `777`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: @harrymc: While the question is _very_ similar (and I was about to suggest setfacl myself), OP is asking how to make _files_ executable by default and that is not something that default ACLs would achieve, at least not in any way I tried -- the '+x' from default ACLs is always ignored when propagating them to files.

Comment: @user1686: Executable by default exists only on Windows. The most that is possible to do is in the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/808345/change-default-permissions-for-new-files-and-folders) I gave as duplicate. This is an unsolvable post, probably an X-Y problem, so any answer will do.

Comment: A convoluted solution may be to use a `cron` job to monitor a directory every `1` min for new files, then use `find` to list files only, piping to `xargs` to change permissions [`find . -type f -name '*' | xargs chmod 777`]. As @harrymc mentioned, Windows is the only OS that requires execute permissions to open files, so if this is for a Windows share, use Samba and specify in the `smb.conf` `create mask = 0777`

Comment: @JW0914: Windows doesn't require +x to open files, it requires +x to _execute_ files -- in other words, +x on a file has the same meaning on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @user1686 Ah, I mistyped and meant to say _modify_ not _open_. Execute permission doesn't mean the same thing in Windows and Linux - to modify a file in Windows that resides in Linux w/ UGO permissions, execute is a required permission, whereas in Unix-based OSes, write is all that's required. This can be seen in Advanced Security dialogue for a file in Windows, as once `Traverse folder / execute file` is removed, so is `Modify`, and is why at least `700` is required when modifying files in a Linux Samba share from Windows _(at least in Samba v3, as OpenWrt's v4 port isn't stable quite yet)_

Comment: @JW0914: That is not true. The "Permissions" dialog only works this way because "Modify" is a combination of both "Read & Execute" plus "Write" -- but that doesn't mean that "Execute" is part of "Write". In practice, you can still change files even if you lack the Execute permission on them.

Comment: @JW0914: The only real difference between Windows and Unix-likes is that on Windows all users get a process-level privilege which bypasses "Traverse folder", so they can still access items within folders which they don't have +x for. (But this doesn't extend to files -- even on Windows you cannot execute an .exe file if you don't have +x for it, even if you have all other permissions.)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys . So , does that mean by default in linux the maximum permission for a file on its creation is 666 ? and also I cannot make file permission to executable on its creation in linux ?

Answer (score 2):

You really can't - there is no "default file permission" on POSIX systems.

File permissions are set when the file is created with either the [`open()`/`openat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) or [`creat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/creat.html) function.

Per the `open()` specifications (note the bolded part, added to emphasize where file permission bits come from):

> `O_CREAT`
>
> If the file exists, this flag has no effect except as noted under
> `O_EXCL` below. Otherwise, if `O_DIRECTORY` is not set the file shall
> be created as a regular file; the user ID of the file shall be set to
> the effective user ID of the process; the group ID of the file shall
> be set to the group ID of the file's parent directory or to the
> effective group ID of the process; and **the access permission bits
> (see [<sys/stat.h>](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)) of the file mode shall be set to the value of
> the argument following the `oflag` argument taken as type `mode_t`
> modified as follows: a bitwise AND is performed on the file-mode bits
> and the corresponding bits in the complement of the process' file mode
> creation mask.** ...

The application creating the file picks the file's initial permissions, but with the bits that are non-zero in the process `umask` setting set to zero.

There is no "default" permission setting.

Comment: This depends on the context - for example, Samba can be configured to apply default permissions on created files and/or directories in a share within the `smb.conf`

Comment: @JW0914 That just means Samba is setting permissions how it wants to, and likely explicitly calling [`[f]chmod()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chmod.html) **after** file creation to ensure permissions are set per the Samba application's settings.  The operating system is not not providing those default settings.

Comment: Would a convoluted solution then be to use a `cron` job to monitor  a directory every `1` min for new files, then use `find` to list files only, piping to `xargs` to change permissions? [`find . -type f -name '*' | xargs chmod 777`]